# Match an array of date strings to the current calendar selection

Tags: javascript, performance

I have an input array of month-year strings of disabled months selected by the user:

```
disabledDates = [
    "2020-01",
    "2014-07",
    "2020-03",
    "2011-08"
    "2011-10"
]
```

(But it can be much longer)

The user is displayed a calendar with years and months only - he can select an year using a dropdown. For each year I want to grey out the month cubes that are disabled in the given array.

Right now my solution does not seem too performant: I convert each string to date and get the year using `new Date().getFullYear()` every time a user selects an year and check for every date if it matches the current selected year and if so I use `getMonth()` to grey out matching months:

```
let disabledMonths = [];
let dateObject;

disabledDates.forEach(function(date) {
    dateObject = new Date(date);
    if (dateObject.getFullYear() === currentSelectedYear) {
    disabledMonths.push(dateObject.getMonth());
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    if (disabledMonths.includes(i)) {
        calendarElement.innerHtml += `<div class="disabled_month"...>`;
    } else {
        calendarElement.innerHtml += `<div ...>`;
    }
}
```

But I think it does unnecessary iterations every time. Maybe there's a better way, such as "grouping" all the dates by years, then only if there's a matching year in this group - get the months and grey them out. But is something like that possible?

( Also, I want to also add the same feature but when displaying days as well, so it can be an array of full dates:

```
disabledDates = [
    "2020-01-01",
    "2014-07-12",
    "2020-03-30",
    "2011-08-11"
    "2011-10-05"
]
```

so that might add more iterations
)

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: The "month-year" strings appear to be "year-month" order instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to first map the disabled months for the year. You can directly check with `disabledDates.includes()` by prefixing the month with the selected year.

```js
for (let month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
    const date = currentSelectedYear + "-" + String(month).padStart(2, '0');
    
    if (disabledDates.includes(date)) {
        calendarElement.innerHtml += `<div class="disabled_month"...>`;
    } else {
        calendarElement.innerHtml += `<div ...>`;
    }
}
```